# .htaccess affect other file url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I am trying to make .htaccess rule not affect other file url

example
my .htaccess rule is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /tr/hp.php?q=$1 [L]
```

my site url is

```
mydomain.com/keywords
```

everything working good on keywords but when I try to open robots.txt

```
mydomain.com/robots.txt
```

OR

```
mydomain.com/images.jpg
```

any other file url

redirect on /tr/hp.php?q=filename

which .htaccess Rewrite Rule works on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
#--exclude real directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#--and files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /tr/hp.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to prevent matching any request pattern that carries a dot in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$ /tr/hp.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Certainly it is possible to further refine this pattern.

---

Alternatively some people like to prevent rewriting requests to files or folders that physically exist in the file system using `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

But that is something you have to decide upon. This does not help for example if resources like `robots.txt` are delivered in a dynamic manner...